# Loading new cells added from Parse data class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xcode6, tableview

I'm creating an app for clothing shop and I'm using parse cloud to upload and retrieve data from it. But when I add a new item to the data class, it loads at the bottom of the tableview.

How can I make the new items or the new cells load from the top of the table view like at the first cell?

I'm using PFQueryTableView from Parse instead of the original tableView.

Comment: well, if you always want new items to be on top you should prepend them, instead of append them to the item array

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `PFQuery` then you can trial & error using:

`– orderByAscending:`
OR
`– orderByDescending:` - right after you update the data source.

Also, you might want to check out [This Discussion.](https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections)

Let me know, if it works for you.